# Video written with Streamlit shows a single static frame instead of the actual video

Tags: python, streamlit

I am making a facial expressions recognition system on Streamlit. The system is able to let user to upload a video on Streamlit and the uploaded video will be processed and display the result (emotions) in video form. But current problem is the system only displays the static image of the uploaded video, not the entire video.

Below is the code for the mentioned part:

```
FRAME_WINDOW = st.image([])
uploaded_video = st.file_uploader("Upload Video")
    if uploaded_video is not None:
        tfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) 
        tfile.write(uploaded_video.read())
  
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(tfile.name)

        _, frame = camera.read()
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        emotion_dict = {0: "Angry", 1: "Disgusted", 2: "Fearful", 3: "Happy", 4: "Neutral", 5: "Sad", 6: "Surprised"}

        # load json and create model
        json_file = open('./model/model4.json', 'r')
        loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
        json_file.close()
        emotion_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

        # load weights into new model
        emotion_model.load_weights("./model/model4.h5")

        face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        gray_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # detect faces available on camera
        num_faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray_frame, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)

        # take each face available on the camera and Preprocess it
        for (x, y, w, h) in num_faces:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y-50), (x+w, y+h+10), (0, 255, 0), 4)
            roi_gray_frame = gray_frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
            cropped_img = np.expand_dims(np.expand_dims(cv2.resize(roi_gray_frame, (48, 48)), -1), 0)

            # predict the emotions
            emotion_prediction = emotion_model.predict(cropped_img)
            maxindex = int(np.argmax(emotion_prediction))
            cv2.putText(frame, emotion_dict[maxindex], (x+5, y-20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
            FRAME_WINDOW.image(frame)
```

Below is the output after uploading the video:
[image]

Is there any additional code needed or mistake in the code? Thank you for the help.

Comment: you say you _do_ get output 'after uploading' (???) but then you say the video _doesn't play_? which is it? sounds contradictory to me.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I mean the output is not what it's expected. It just displayed a _static image_ instead of a _played video_. Sorry for the unclear explanation.

Comment: which commands in your code write the output video? you don't appear to use OpenCV for writing the video.